# OverflowError relating to compareTo

Tags: java, compareto

I have a class Item, which implements Comparable, and has a compareTo method. I want to compare the object o to other Items. I casted o to Item.

In a separate class, Inventory, I have a method for inserting items into the inventory. But I only want to insert if their product numbers are different. So I try to call the compareTo() method to compare item numbers but get a stackoverflow error.

I've tried p.compareTo(iter.next), because I want it to cycle through all of the items in the list. Sorry the formatting isn't perfect. first post here.

```
public class item{
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        result = compareTo((Product)o);         
        if (result < 0){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (result == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

public class ProductInventory extends Product {
    private void insert(Product p){
        Iterator<Product> iter = list.iterator();
        if (list.size() == 0) {
            list.addFirst(p);           
        }
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            p.compareTo(iter.next());           
            //if (p.getNumber() != iter.next().getNumber()) {
            System.out.print("RESULT:" + result);
            if (result != 0) {
                list.addFirst(p);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("DUPLICATE");
            }
            iter.next();
        }
}
```

I want it to print duplicate if result = 0 (the numbers are the same), otherwise add it to list.

Comment: `Item` or `Product`? For which class do you want `compareTo()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `compareTo` method in your item class is infinitely recursing on this line:

```
result = compareTo((Product)o); //this is a self-call!
```

You want to replace that line with the implementation for your `compareTo`, for example:

```
result = this.value - that.value; //insert actual logic here
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have seen this. and that. around as I searched for help... I know how this. works in constructors... I am unsure of how to extend that knowledge to other methods. I'm just struggling to understanding what two values I could use in this method, since there is only 1 parameter. Obviously when I can it in Inventory, I'll have the new item and all of the others. But I'm failing to understand how to put two values in the method itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```java
public class ProductInventory extends Product {
    private void insert(Product p) {
        if (!list.contains(p)) {
            list.add(0, p);
        }
    }
}
```